# `tar c <file> | tar x` writes the file to an unexpected path

Tags: tar, archive

If I use the following command:

```
cd /Users/you/foo 
tar c /Users/you/x/y/z | tar x
```

it will write `/Users/you/x/y/z` to the local directory to this path:

```
/Users/you/foo/Users/you/x/y/z
```

how can I change one of the tar commands, so the file gets written here instead:

```
/Users/you/foo/z
```

man tar on my MacOS machine did not yield any obvious solutions to this one, and I am not sure if this behavior can be changed.

Comment: Your actual and desired paths are exactly the same.

Comment: ah thanks for the correction, that was a typo, I think I have an answer, the one I posted seems to work

Comment: Can you use [pax](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pax.1.html)? It can write tar files (with the `-x ustar` option), and the `-s` option can be used to rewrite pathnames. When we needed to make archives that could be read and written on Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, and Mac OS X, `pax` was a great, portable solution

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks, I am on MacOS, and have to support other ppl, so if many ppl don't already have `pax` then prob not easy to incorporate pax. One problem I have is that the -O options seems only support one file being written on. If `tar c <file1> <file2> ... <filex>` is used then it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I added the new problem I am seeing as part of my answer to the OP

Answer (score 2):

What I do when copying stuff around is:

```
tar c here/is/the/stuff | (cd /where/it/should/go; tar x)
```

Explanation: The first `tar` packages to standard output, this is piped to the second command, which is a subshell (the `(` starts it) which changes directory and then runs the second `tar`. This is nice if you want to use e.g. file completion for messy names. Or you could use the `-C` option to change directory before doing the operation, like:

```
tar c here/is/the/stuff | tar -C /where/it/should/go -x
```

Comment: Correct, one of the main rules: **Thou shalt not use absolute path names in tar archives**

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this to work using the -O option of `tar x` which allows you to write the output to stdout, so that looks like:

```
tar c /Users/you/x/y/z | tar x -O > z.tgz
```

one problem with this technique is that it doesn't seem to support writing out multiple files:

```
tar c z1 z2 z3 | tar x -O > z.tgz
```

it looks like z.tgz will just represent z3...

Comment: `tar x -O` makes no sense, and the result definitely won't be a gzipped tarfile.